# RESTful service in Karaf without blueprint xml

Tags: java, rest, osgi, karaf

I am new to Karaf, hence was looking for resources to create a project for RESTful web services using felix annotations and without the use of BundleActivator class(i mean by an actual class that needs to be written by me, but its ok if some compiler or maven plugin does the same for me) and blueprint xml file. So far I got success in the first part(BundleActivator part) which now after compilation auto creates my MANIFEST.MF with import and export statements, creates the relevant XML file for each component class, and packages it into a a nice jar bundle which works very well when I deploy it on Karaf container. But what is not working is the RESTful services. The bundle is deployed correctly, but the REST urls are not exposed and hence I am unable to access them.

Please help me in getting this done. I don't want to write an XML file which needs to be modified everytime there is an addition or deletion of a rest service.

Thanks

Comment: You can use Declarative Service and Jersey, look at https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment.osgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do so without using the CXF feature. That is, create a component class and in activate method get the object of ConfigurationAdmin and put the required context path against the jersy server process(using jersey publisher jar). Using this mehtod, I was able to deploy any rest/serlvet in Karaf without using blueprint.xml file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to completely avoid blueprint then you should use cxf-dosgi. You simply annotate your rest service using jaxrs and publish it as an OSGi service with some special properties.

See the [cxf-dosgi rest sample](https://github.com/apache/cxf-dosgi/tree/master/samples/rest).

The example uses the standard DS annotation and the maven bundle plugin to create the DS component xml on the fly.

If you prefer to have blueprint at runtime then you can use the blueprint-maven-plugin. [See this example](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist/tasklist-persistence/src/main/java/net/lr/tasklist/persistence/impl/TaskServiceImpl.java).